# WHMCS API-- provisioning mySQL

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm, whmcs

I'm trying to use the WHMCS API / provisioning module to auto-create a mysql database for a new WHM / cPanel client after their order for hosting goes through.

It seems like it should be simple enough to do, but I can't find anything about it in the docs. The WHMCS module is connected to the WHMCS mysql instance, but I would want to be connecting the "main" local mysql instance where the client's data is held.

Would I simply connect to localhost in the provisioning module, and create a new database and user? Or is there a more robust way to handle this without going outside the WHMCS / WHM system.

Please provide examples if possible!

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question probably belongs to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I posted at serverfault-- still haven't got a single answer.

Comment: I am sorry, your question might be off-topic at ServerFault too, but I couldn't tell for sure. Perhaps [try their forum](http://forum.whmcs.com/).

Comment: Question [reposted at ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/644542/155703).

Comment: @randomseed- thanks. I did try their forum. No answer there either!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [whmcs's hooks](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks). A hook is function that is fired as a result of an internal action.

You should look for the invoice items after the [invoice is paid](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:InvoicePaidPreEmail) but before the email in case you want to send database information  if not then [after paid](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:InvoicePaid) should be fine

This would go in billing dir / includes / hooks

and it would look like

```
function init_InvoicePaidPreEmail($vars) {
 // create your db code here be sure to look for the specific invoice item "order for hosting"

}
add_hook("InvoicePaidPreEmail",1,"init_InvoicePaidPreEmail","");
```